# Spring mvs - responceEntity(status ok) sending to ajax (but error-section called)

Tags: java, ajax, веб-программирование, spring

Посылаю запрос на сервер - сохраняю данные с формы в БД (здесь все норм), и пытаюсь вернуть на сервер обновленные даные с БД но у ajax срабатывает error секция, притом что дебагер показывает на успешный запрос

```
00:29:44.587 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
00:29:44.587 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

код ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'addAcc',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(acc),
        success: function (result) {
            alert('its ok');
            //alert(result);
        },
        error : function (xhrv) {
            //alert("error");
            alert(JSON.stringify(xhrv));
        }
    });
```

PS:JSON.stringify(xhrv) возвращает 0 статус, 0 стадию и еррор текст

контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "addAcc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getBooking(@RequestBody AccountDto accDto, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n data is on server \n\n\n\n");
    if (!(accountService.findByName(accDto.getName()) == null)) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Account already exsists");
    }
    //todo: if (accountValidator.validateAccount(accDto));
    Account acc = new Account(accDto);
    accountRepo.save(acc);
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n data is on sevbxcvbnrver1 woo \n\n\n\n");
    List<AccountDto> listAccDto = accountService.getAccDto(accountRepo.findAll());
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n data is on sevbxcvbnrver2 woo \n\n\n\n");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new Gson().toJson(listAccDto));
}
```

PS: sout-ты все выводяться

Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Откройте консоль браузера и посмотрите с каким кодом пришел HTTP response. Откройте консоль или лог приложения и посмотрите какой exception оно выкинуло. Возможно ошибка сериализации или еще что-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что кнопка (по которой выполняеться запрос), была типа submit - из-за чего происходила прерывание request-a, и на клиента приходил пустой ответ